# Set variable programmatically without triggering onChange

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I have the following toggle in ionic:

```
<ion-toggle (ionChange)="changeConfirmation($event)" [(ngModel)]="check" color="tertiary">
```

And this is `changeConfirmation()` function.

```
  changeConfirmation(event) {  // should only happen when manually toggled
    this.user.changeConfirmation(this.date, this.check, this.userData)
    this.toast.showToast(`Your name has been ${this.check ? 'added to' : 'removed from'} the list`, 'top')
  }
```

The toggle value is set to true/false in my code when the component is rendered depending on data I retrieve from a database. When the variable is set, the `changeConfirmation()` function is also called due to the `ionChange` function. How can I only call this function if the user manually toggled the toggle?

Comment: `Set variable problematically`? I would suggest to set it `programmatically`. :-)

Comment: Oh damn thats one bad typo.

Comment: Can you clarify? Angular’s change detection’s job is to figure out when a value changes. There is no logical reason to want to not have it do that.

Comment: @themayer The toggle represents the user's RSVP state which he/she may change so when the page loads the toggle should be set to the user's current state. The ionChange function shows a custom modal which tells the user his RSVP status has changed and now its triggered when the toggle is initially set

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest to go reactive. It has cool features, including what you now are looking for... i.e when setting value programatically you can define that it does not trigger event, in this case `valueChanges` of a form control. By the way, if this is a form, I would suggest further that you move on to a reactive form! But let's just use a "simple" formcontrol here:

```ts
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

// ...

myToggle = new FormControl();
formCtrlSub = new Subscription();

constructor() {
  // is fired when value changes
  this.formCtrlSub = this.myToggle.valueChanges.subscribe((value: boolean) => {
    console.log('user changed value!')
  })
}

// for testing setting value in Onit
// set the boolean value using setValue()
// adding emitEvent:false will not trigger valueChanges
ngOnInit() {
  this.myToggle.setValue(true, { emitEvent: false})
}

ngOnDestroy() {
  // remember to unsubscribe!!
  this.formCtrlSub.unsubscribe();
}
```

Then in template attach the formcontrol, and you can remove `ionChange` since we are listening to `valueChanges`:

```html
<ion-toggle [formControl]="myToggle"></ion-toggle>
```

**[STACKBLITZ SAMPLE](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-79y1zn?file=pages/home/home.html)**